# PHP Exec Solaris svcadm

Tags: php, solaris, exec

I am attempting to execute a svcadm command from PHP on a Solaris machine.

I have the following function which currently has two commands, who and the svcadm command I really want to run.

I am also aware that this code is very insecure and should never be exposed publicly.

```
private function RestartApacheImmediately(){
    var_dump($this->exec_enabled());
    $output = array();
    $returnvar = "";
    $cmd = 'who 2>&1';
    //$cmd = 'svcadm -v restart apache 2>&1';
    echo $cmd;
    $return = exec($cmd, $output, $returnvar);
    var_dump($output);
    var_dump($return);
    var_dump($returnvar);
}
```

When I execute who, I get two users: x and y.

Both x and y are configured as Service Management profiles in /etc/user_attr .

When a run the commented out $cmd above, I get the following output to stderr:

```
svcadm: Could not set restarter_actions/auxiliary_tty property of svc:/network/http:apache: permission denied.
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:  Resolution was as follows:

I got this to work by using the user_attr method I described above. However, what I discovered was that the httpd daemon was running as a different user than php reported upon executing the 'who' command. So it wasn't x or y, it was z.  I determined this by doing a simple ps -e while logged in as root at the shell.

Comment: I guess that `svcadm` has to be run as root. How are you running this code? From what user?

Comment: @netcode Not from root, from a nameless user lets call them x, but adding them to /etc/user_attr is supposed to allow you to freely run svcadm as this article states: http://wiki.joyent.com/solaris:kb:smf

Comment: It's probably not working judging from the error message. What if you `su` as user *x* and execute it... does it work?

Comment: @netcoder It does from the console, can I su inside of an exec statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add auths (**value_authorization**) to SMF Manifest on Apache HTTPD to perform the *state value change* as you can see above in a Apache Tomcat Example.

The **value_authorization** must be declared on **/etc/security/auth_attr**, for example,

```
# echo "solaris.org.apache.smf.value.tomcat:::Change value of Apache Tomcat::" >> /etc/security/auth_attr
# echo "solaris.org.apache.smf.manage.tomcat:::Manage Apache Tomcat service states::" >> /etc/security/auth_attr
```

And then edit the SMF Manifest to add the custom **value_authorization**, first on global section

```
<property_group name='general' type='framework'>
        <propval
             name='value_authorization'
             type='astring'
            value='solaris.org.apache.smf.value.tomcat' />
        <propval
            name='action_authorization'
            type='astring'
            value='solaris.org.apache.smf.manage.tomcat' />
</property_group>
```

And also on the method section you need to add the auth

```
   <property_group name='tomcat_6' type='application'>
                        <propval name='home' type='astring'
                           value='/opt/www/tomcat-6.0' />
                        <propval name='jvmargs' type='astring'
                           value='-d32 -Xms64m -Xmx128m' />
                        <propval name='java_home' type='astring'
                           value='/usr/java' />
             <propval name='value_authorization' type='astring'
                           value='solaris.org.apache.smf.value.tomcat' />
   </property_group>
```

I have an example (in Spanish) in my blog to put [Apache Tomcat using RBAC and SMF](http://sparcki.blogspot.com/2010/10/modelo-de-seguridad-de-solaris-rbac.html)

And at the end, you *must add* auth to the *role* or *user* running the script

```
# usermod -A solaris.org.apache.smf.manage.tomcat,solaris.org.apache.smf.value.tomcat webope
```

or for **role**

```
# rolemod -A solaris.org.apache.smf.manage.tomcat,solaris.org.apache.smf.value.tomcat webope
```

I hope it helps you,

Urko

Comment: Thank you for the in depth description Urko.  I actually got this to work by using the user_attr method I described above. However, what I discovered was that the httpd daemon was running as a different user than php reported upon executing the 'who' command.  I determined this by doing a simple ps -e while logged in as root at the shell.

Answer (score 1):

Is the PHP process executing as a user that has permissions to perform the svcadm action?  I tested the code you posted and got a similar result if php was running as a normal user.

```
/usr/local/bin/php apacherestart.php
```

but if I

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/php apacherestart.php
```

it worked fine for me and in fact gave me a few ideas of things I could do :)

Comment: Interesting Dustin, I was attempting not to sudo as that is supposedly less secure than using the /etc/user_attr config file solaris provides.  I will give it a try though and see if it works.